# React Native Error: Invariant Violation: View config not found for name RNC safe Area

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

Hey everyone I am new to React Native and cannot figure this simple error out. Looked everywhere no solutions :[ The image provided shows the error I Keep getting. I am working from a windows 10 machine. I am using Expo, NPM, React-Native... Ive been stuck and tried to follow a few tutorials on 2020 react native Navigation I keep getting this error w them all.

[Emulator Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4knf7.png)

App.js

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import * as React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import Home from './screens/Home';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
     <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Home.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Button, Text } from 'react-native';

/**
 * Home screen
 */
export default class Home extends React.Component {

    render() {  
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>

            </View>
        );

    }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    }
});
```

package.json

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.5.0",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.4.1",
    "expo": "~37.0.3",
    "react": "~16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.9.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-37.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.0.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.8.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    "react-navigation": "^4.3.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.1.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.6"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would help to C&P the error stack in rather than uploading it as an image somewhere and providing a link. The link is easily overlooked and an image makes it impossible to highlight text, or for a reader to read.

Comment: You can use https://www.onlineocr.net/ to get the text from your screenshot

Comment: Have you got an app.json file? If not, try adding and rerunning expo upgrade. https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/8563

Answer (score 1):

You should use `expo install react-native-safe-area-context` to get the correct version. The [installation instructions for React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started#installing-dependencies-into-an-expo-managed-project) also advise this. I'd also check out the [Using Libraries](https://docs.expo.io/workflow/using-libraries/) docs page for more info. Lastly, I imagine you're getting a warning when you start your project about library incompatibility, be sure to keep an eye out for those warnings in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I install the correct files but now I am seeing: Unable to resolve "./SafeAreaContext" from "node_modules\react-native-safe-area-context\src\index.tsx"
Failed building JavaScript bundle.